# Product Rule for multidimensional functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am struggeling to find the derivative of
$f(x) = a^T(x)  b(x)  c(x)$, where $a,b,c,x$ are all $\in R^{3x1}$.

Using single variable chain rule I get:
$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(a^T(x)\right) * b(x) * c(x) + ...$

However, already here I am hold back by a dimension mismatch:
A vector derived by a vector should be a matrix, so $\frac{d}{dx}(a^T(x))$ should be a $3x3$ matrix. Multiplying this matrix with $b(x)$ would yield a $3x1$ column vector. And multiplying this with $c(x)$ would result in a dimension mismatch.

What am I missing?
Thx in advance

Comment: The safest thing is to use indices and either summation signs or Einstein convention. Then use the product rule. This will show how the result can be translated back to matrix vector multiplication. We cannot always assume that every notation does every job for us.

Comment: Use \times (in math mode), not $x$, for the multiplication symbol.

Comment: Your original product is not defined. Matrix multiplication is associative and $bc$ is certainly not defined. So it’s not the fault of the differentiation.